# Suggest require and/or require-dev in composer.json

Tags: composer-php

I know that if I want to suggest some library in my composer, I can do this.

```
"suggest": {
    "vendor/library": "A description"
},
```

But, is there a way to suggest for `require` or for `require-dev`? Could I simply add a comment for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description in the suggest line can be used for anything you want the developer to see, including suggestions on whether to require the package for development.

On the other hand, the differences between require and require-dev are few. Both get installed by default. You'd only interfere if you don't want to install that 100 MB "development only" package that will never ever get used in your production code and wastes precious space on the server.